# Codeigniter 3: pagination only displays the first 10 records

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to paginate a **Codeigniter 3** application without using the framework's pagination library. More exactly, I want to *paginate a table with about 100 rows*. For this purpose:

In the home controller I have:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('Customer');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url("index.php"),
        'per_page' => 10,
        'total_rows' => $this->Customer->get_num_rows(),
        'uri_segment' => 3,
        'first_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'full_tag_open' =>  '<ul class="pagination">',
        'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
        'next_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'prev_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open' =>   '<li>',
        'num_tag_close' =>  '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open' =>   '<li class="active"><a>',
        'cur_tag_close' =>  '</a></li>',
    ];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']));
    $this->load->view('home', ['records'=>$customers]);
}
```

In the Model file I have:

```
class Customer extends CI_Model {
 public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
 }

 public function getCustomers($limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get('customers');
    return $query->result();
 }
}
```

Finaly, the view:

```
<div class="pagination-container text-center">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

The pagination is displayed and properly formatted; so are the **first 10 records**:
[image]

But if I click on page 2, or any other page, I get the **same first 10 records** as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The url of page 2 is:

```
http://localhost/cicrud/index.php?page=2
```

I did something wrong, I can't understand what. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: If the controller you are operating out of is cicrud, then your base_url should not be /. Also, the uri_segment is probably 2, not 5.

Comment: pass the offset as default in public function index($offset=0)

Comment: change also in the model  function getCustomers($limit=null,$offset=null){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `GET` method, must to add `$this->input->get('page'/*your query string segment*/);` instead of `$this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']);.`

Comment: My  query string segment, as cam be seen below is `'query_string_segment' => 'page',`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these config lines too...

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
$config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Ok, I no longer get the "Object not found!" message from the browser. Thanks for help. But clicking a pagination item does not the corresponding records. I still only see _the first 10 only_ :(

Comment: You need to create a model to query the table from a given start position
( select * from table limit 0,10) - if page = 1 or empty 
( select * from table limit 10,10) - if page = 2 or empty

example:
**getCustomers($config['per_page'],$page_num*$config['per_page']-$config['per_page'])**

Answer (score 0):

So, the index() function has to look like this:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('Customer');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url("index.php"),
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'query_string_segment' => 'page',
        'display_pages' => TRUE,
        'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
        'per_page' => 10,
        'total_rows' => $this->Customer->get_num_rows(),
        'uri_segment' => 3,
        'first_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'full_tag_open' =>  '<ul class="pagination">',
        'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
        'next_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'prev_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open' =>   '<li>',
        'num_tag_close' =>  '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open' =>   '<li class="active"><a>',
        'cur_tag_close' =>  '</a></li>'
    ];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($config['per_page'], $this->input->get('page'));
    $this->load->view('home', ['records'=>$customers]);
}
```

Hope my answer will be useful to others. Many thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
 'uri_segment' => 3,
```

to

```
 'uri_segment' => 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your function better readable I modify few variable names, and create pagination like below :

```
 /*
      $perpage - is nothing but limit value, no of records to display 
      $page    - is nothing but offset, thats page number 
 */
 public function getCustomers($perpage=10, $page=0) {
        $page = $page-1;
        if ($page<0) { 
            $page = 0;
        }
        /* decides from where to start*/
        $from = $page*$perpage;
        $this->db->limit($perpage, $from);
        $query = $this->db->get('customers');
        return $query->result();
 }
```